# How is ProcDump implemented? Is it essentially a debugger?

Tags: debugging, sysinternals, procdump

I am interested in the internals of [ProcDump](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) (a Sysinternals utility): is it essentially a debugger? How does it manage to dump a process on exceptions, first chance exceptions and even managed (CLR) exceptions?

I can see that it has imports such as DebugActiveProcess from kernel32.dll. Its strings also contain names of CLR libraries so I assume it dynamically loads them to make use of the CLR debugging API (although I don't see mscordbi.dll in the strings - should I?).

Answer (score 2):

I will try to give an elementary answer to my own question, after taking a look at ProcDump with IDA Pro.

At least for the unmanaged side, ProcDump seems to make use of the Win32 debugging API: it uses DebugActiveProcess and a debug loop of WaitForDebugEvent & ContinueDebugEvent. Then, depending on the startup parameters, it can e.g. inspect an exception and dump the contents from ReadProcessMemory into a IO device.